# An indentity for $2$-tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I'm self-study Riemannian Geometry and I'm trying understand the Lemma on page 4 of [this notes](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m667s08/m667s08SimonsIdentity.pdf). I would like to know why it's possible extend locally the vector fields so that all covariant derivatives vanish at $p$. I know that it's possible extend locally vector fields, but I don't know why is possible do this extension so that all covariant derivatives vanish at $p$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're familiar with them, geodesic normal coordinates based at $p$ make this very easy: just extend the vector field to have constant components. Alternatively, you can use arbitrary coordinates centred on $p$ and extend the vector field to have linear polynomial components, with coefficients chosen to offset the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{jk}(p).$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1494295/2002) for a reference.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, thanks a lot! I understood the justification using normal coordinates, but, just for curiosity, how can I do the extension of the vector field just like you the suggested in arbitrary coordinates?

Comment: @YuriVyatkin, I was thought use Bianchi identity, but the identity it's for three vector fields, but I have two vector fields and one $2$-tensor in lemma .

Comment: Sorry, George. My link was supposed to point to Jack Lee's answer where he gives precises reference to his book's pages. Try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1494295/2002) one.