# Proving $R_{ij;m}=g^{kl} R_{ikjl;m}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

> In the coordinate $\{x^i\}$, the Riemann curvature tensor can be written as
>   $$
> R=R_{ijkl}\,dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes dx^k \otimes dx^l
> $$
>   and the Ricci curvature can be written as
>   $$\text{Ric}=R_{ij}\,dx^i\otimes dx^j$$
>   where$R_{ij}=g^{kl} R_{kilj}\,$.
>   Prove that
>   $$R_{ij;m}=g^{kl} R_{ikjl;m}$$
>   where
>   $$\theta_{i_1i_2\cdots i_s;m}=\left(D_{\partial_m}\theta\right)(\partial_{i_1},\cdots,\partial_{i_s})\,.$$

**My attempt**

I got a hint to prove
 $$R_{jk;m} = (g^{il}R_{ijkl})_{;m} =  g^{il}{}_{;m}R_{ijkl} + g^{il}R_{ijkl;m} = g^{il}R_{ijkl;m}\tag{1}$$
and
$$g^{il}{}_{;m}=0 \,.\tag{2}$$

As for $(2)$, I am not sure what the meaning of $g^{il}{}_{;m}$ is.
I thought that 
$$
g^{il}{}_{;m}=\left(D_{\partial_m}\,\check g\right)(dx^i,dx^l)
$$
where $\check g(\alpha,\beta)=g(\alpha^\sharp, \beta^\sharp)$ is the dual metric in which $\sharp$ denotes the [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).
Am I right?

I can prove that $Dg=0$ and hence $g_{ij;k}=0$. I hope to use this to prove $(2)$, and I tried to take advantage of $g^{il}g_{lj}=\delta^i_j$. And then I guess that
$$(g^{il}g_{lj})_{;m}=g^{il}{}_{;m}g_{lj}+g^{il}g_{lj;m}$$
but I don't know whether this is right, and I don't know how to get $(1)$. They are similar and seem like leibniz rule. Could we conclude that? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The middle equality of your Equation (1) is the second Bianchi identity.  A proof has been discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494262/direct-proof-of-the-second-bianchi-identity) question.

You have the right interpretation of $g^{ij}{}_{;m}$, and are correct that $(g^{ij}g_{jk})_{;m}=g^{ij}{}_{;m}g_{jk} + g^{ij}g_{jk;m}$.  Since $Dg=0$ and the identity tensor $\delta_k^i$ is clearly parallel, this shows that $g^{ij}{}_{;m}g_{jk}=0$.  Multiply both sides by $g^{kl}$ to see that $g^{il}{}_{;m}=0$.

This should resolve each of your questions in Equation (1).